# Changing alpha of an MC on hover

Tags: actionscript-3, mouseover, movieclip

This looks like it should work to me, but clearly I've done something wrong. I don't know what exactly and this is apparently to much of a novice mistake to find answers searching Google, so help would be appreciated.

```
this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER,function() {
        this.alpha=0
        })
```

In an MC, I want it to become invisible when the mouse hovers over it. The reason I'm putting this code inside the MC and not making an instance out of it is because this MC will recur numerous times. The listener does work, as tested with trace(). For whatever reason, alpha doesn't. Thanks for any help.

Comment: "Doesn't work" is really poor description for any problem. It always requires clarifications - whether it has no effect, or phases out something other than target clip, or something else. How it doesn't work?

Comment: Clearly the person who answered understood the problem. If you knew enough about the problem to answer, you'd know what "this" won't affect something else. Instead, it'll affect "this" (the MC with the code) or nothing (in this case).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using closure as you are (using an anonymous function inline) you lose scope. `this` is not the object that you're hovering over.

You can get around that using

```
var me:DisplayObject = this;
```

and then (corrected code)

```
addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER,function(event:MouseEvent):void {
    me.alpha=0
})
```

note that I also put an event:MouseEvent parameter in your listener because otherwise you'd get runtime errors (didn't you get those already?)

Comment: I only get event errors when using external functions in events. Closure, as you call it, never gives me errors. I also wondered why, but it works for me. I guess it's a CS4 thing. Also thanks for clearing up the reasoning behind why it wasn't working.